# Upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 unable to resolve hosts now

Tags: ubuntu, hostname

I have updated to 12.04 from 10.04 where there was no problem reaching outside ip's hostnames.

Now however I can not:

```
 root@sub:~# resolveip google.com
 resolveip: Unable to find hostid for 'google.com': try again
```

If i try to access `resolv.conf` it is reported back as `file does not exist`.

How can I access outside sources now?

Answer (score 1):

You could open a terminal and try this;

`sudo touch /etc/resolv.conf`
`sudo dhclient`

I am assuming that you are using DHCP since you have not just recreated the file and populated it your self. This will recreate the missing file and tell your DHCP client to get updated IP and DNS information.

A second option will be to turn off your network manager off so that it does not overwrite your changes and populate the /etc/resolv.conf file your self with your preferred DNS servers.

This does not answer your question though. The only way to contact the outside world without DNS is to use IP addresses. This means that you will have to know in advance what the IP addresses of the different service you want to contact are.

Comment: NO luck with this, although both commands did complete, I still can't hit outside things :(

Comment: I needed to add nameserver 8.8.8.8 to my resolv.conf.. :)